# Is there any downside in enabling Dev Hub

Tags: salesforcedx

Is there any downside in enabling dev hub in production org. Will I be able to use existing sandboxes and create new sandboxes after enabling dev hub.

Only few developers will be using scratch org and others will be using Sandboxes. We are not planning to switch to package based deployment in near future. We mainly want to enable dev hub/scratch org so that our developers can locally develop lightning web components

Comment: 10-month update request - Have there been any issues enabling it in Prod?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problem, you'll still be able to create sandboxes from your production org as well as creating dx orgs with new dev hub credentials.

Comment: @vinny, There is no problem. Please also make sure you give correct permissions to SFDX users - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm